# IIS High cpu usage on azure vm with low inbound flow

Tags: iis, azure, cpu-usage, windows-server-2022, azure-vm

My IIS server running on Azure VM is having occasionally high cpu usage. It happens only on Thursdays, Fridays or Saturdays between 11 AM - 2 PM. CPU usage is 100% and cannot do anything on VM. I can only force shutdown. Even force shutdown takes more than 15 minutes to stop vm in that state. I cannot reproduce the issue.

I have over 300 applications on my IIS 10 on Windows 2022 DataCenter. The inbound calls are quite low. Getting max like 20-30 requests per second. I have more than enough ram. Daily usage doesnt surpass 60% of my RAM. Daily use of cpu doesnt surpass 30%. Note that on same vm I also have MSSQL server. When high cpu happens then I can clearly see that its IIS fault. Whenever I stop it, everything runs normal. I had occasions where I restarted once or twice vm and everything was working normal again for some reason. I observed that on the day of high cpu usage even if only 2-3 clients are using server I see that moving mouse or moving windows in vm through RDP is sluggish. On normal day it works pretty fast. Maybe its some kind of hint related to networking?

What I tried so far to fix issue:

1. Optimize code - I havent found any memory leaks or flaw using profiling tools
2. Disable firewall and antivirus - it didn't do much
3. Buy more RAM and more CPU - still no help
4. Limit IIS apps to only 3 apps by renaming folder of other IIS apps that I want to block so that my clients wont access app - it somehow helped cpu usage was lower around 30-40% but still the vm that I accessed by RDP was running slow. By slow I mean moving mouse was lagging and moving windows around was sluggish.
5. Track high cpu usage by Azure app insights and new relic - no help they both show that there was no high cpu usage. Although they tracked that there was a downtime during malfunction.
6. Ask Azure support for help - they have run diagnostics and according to them everything works fine they didnt found any issues
7. Buy better and faster disks - no help

Is there anything more that I can do to track what is the actual problem with my high cpu usage?

Comment: "Note that on same vm I also have MSSQL server" would be the first thing you might consider to change. Run IIS and SQL Server on different machines, and that's being recommended for a very long time.

Comment: I couldn`t find valid explanation for this approach. Could you help me out with some reasons behind that?

Comment: Tons of discussions were on that topic, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274846/should-sql-server-be-on-the-same-machine-as-your-iis-installation While you might feel adding more RAMs might help, but that's not often true, as the kernel memory usage can still be tight.

Comment: In thread you sent me are general answers that from performance stand point its good to have sql server and iis on 2 different vms. There are no details why is that. I dont see super high usage of both sql server and iis. I only see CPU high usage of IIS.

Comment: If you pay Microsoft support and open a support ticket, via https://support.microsoft.com, you might get more details on why the recommendation was made and why you should make the changes as early as you can. For commercial products like those, not all information is made publicly available, especially around performance issue analysis and tuning.

Comment: Ive opened already 2 tickets. They still dont have clue whats going on.

Comment: What are the specs of the VM? Sizing?If you have a multi core/socket CPU you can set processor affinity for the IIS process in task manager. You can also setup multiple worker processes and application pools.

Comment: I have multicore processor. How affinity would help? How would multiple worker processes and application pools help?
My size: Azure Standard B16ms (16 vcpus, 64 GiB memory)

Comment: I will leave your questions for Turdie to provide details.  If Additional information could be posted - requested in the next comment - some Performance Tuning suggestions will be prepared for you in next 72 hours.

Comment: Additional MySQL DB information request, please.  TWO SETS, A) anchor at NOON of Friday and B) ending about 1 PM on Friday. Please
Azure instance type?, Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Here is one URL to consider related to processor affinity in Windows.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity?view=net-7.0